Electrics arcs or corona effect around a piece of radioactive material in a metallic enclosure. Is there any material documenting this?
Let's say we have a piece of radioactive material emitting mostly alpha particles, held in the center of a metallic enclosure by isolators. Let's say we have a camera pointing inside the enclosure and a vacuum pump allowing us to control the pressure inside.
This radioactive material will emit alpha particles which will become helium atoms by getting two electrons when colliding with the enclosure walls. This way the radio active material should accumulate negative charges and the enclosure should charge positively, which should lead at some point, to electrical arcs or corona effect.
Has this ever been demonstrated ? Is there any material or video about it ?

Alpha particles are ionizing radiation, so they also ionize air molecules. So it is not just the enclosure that will become charged. Since the ionized air is free to move I assume it will move to the material and reduce its charge.

That's why I added the Vacuum pump to remove part or all of the air.
